# Undefined reference when trying to link C++ and Assembly (GCC x86)

Tags: assembly, gcc, x86, g++, ntdll

So I'm trying to make NTDLL Syscalls using Assembly and linking in my C++ project but every time I compile I get a :(.text+0xf2b): undefined reference to `NtClose@4'

(Using NtClose as an example, every function I try to call from assembly on C++ I get this)

Syscalls.S:

```
.text
    .global NtClose

NtClose:
    movl    $0x3000F,       %eax
    movl    $0x4B307170,    %edx
    call    *%edx
    ret     $4
```

Typedef (Syscalls.h):

```
EXTERN_C NTSTATUS NTAPI NtClose(IN HANDLE ObjectHandle);
```

Calling like this (Injection.cpp):

```
NtClose(Thread);
```

Compiling with:

```
CC=gcc
CXX=g++

$(ASM_OBJ_FILES): $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: %.S
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@

$(CPP_OBJ_FILES): $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

And linking like this:

```
$(OUT): $(OBJ_FILES)
    $(CXX) $^ -o $@ $(LNKFLAGS)
```

Yes I am including Syscalls.h

Comment: Mark your function as `__cdecl` or whatever calling convention it is supposed to be.  Right now it looks like the compiler assumes stdcall for which your symbol lacks the required decoration.

Comment: (And if you make it cdecl, use `ret` instead of `ret $4`.)

Answer (score 1):

`NTAPI` (in fact all `stdcall`) functions are decorated with `@N` where N stands for number of arguments. So you'll need to modify name of function accordingly.